# Change the style of cleveref references to sections of other chapters

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, amsbook

When I use `cleveref`-based cross-references to, say, sections in another chapter, these references just print `Section n`. It's then difficult to distinguish references to a section of another chapter from references to a section of the present chapter. I'm using the `amsbook` documentclass, as @Mico points out is important to mention.

**I presume there's a good pre-built solution to this issue---what is the existing pre-built, pre-packaged solution? Again, this is I assume a well-trod issue, so I'd love to know the generally accepted solution rather than rolling my own.**

I'd certainly rather avoid having to manually write `\cref{sec:section} of \cref{chap:chapter}` in the relevant places.

I'd also rather avoid having to change the style to display as `Section n.m` everywhere, or further as `Subsection n.m.k`. Most of the time these references are within the same chapter or section, so it'd be nice to show only external structure when relevant.

I'd be fine with generating `Section m of Chapter n` automatically, or switching to the notation of `Section n.m`, when relevant.

I'm currently using `varioref` as a workaround, and I also use `hyperref` in my document.

The following seem strongly related:

- [The numbering of and references to the subsections of a given section should only use subsection numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54289/the-numbering-of-and-references-to-the-subsections-of-a-given-section-should-onl)
- [Smartly omit chapter number in equation numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102006/smartly-omit-chapter-number-in-equation-numbering)
- [How do I discard a portion of an equation number when cross-referencing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/how-do-i-discard-a-portion-of-an-equation-number-when-cross-referencing)

Comment: Please tell us (a) which document class you employ, (b) how chapters are numbered in the document (arabic numerals?, Roman numerals?, something else?), and (c) how `\thesection` is defined in your document. Your write-up gives the impression that `\thesection` has been (re)defined to show just the section number -- without a chapter number prefix. Is this impression correct?

Comment: @Mico, thank you for the suggestions and improvements! I'm using `amsbook`. chapters, sections and what have you are numbered by arabic numerals. From looking at the documentation, I believe `thesection` is defined thusly: `\def\thesection{\arabic{section}}`. Regardless, I believe your impressions are correct.

Comment: Prefixing the chapter number to cross-referenced section numbers is straightforward if all such cross-references get this treatment. I'm afraid I have no idea how to go about meeting your criterion that the prefixing of the chapter number in a cross-reference should occur only if the cross-reference pertains to a section *not* in the current chapter.

Comment: @user194021, thank you for the related suggestion! I hadn't looked at this as a "parent counter" problem. I think the crux of the difference in the _questions_, as far as I can tell, is that I'm looking for some pre-built, pre-packaged solution to crack this, rather than rolling my own. It seems like my preferred solution will be `zref`-related, but I need to continue looking at the relevant questions' answers.